# Is possible to use ~/ssh/config file to setup Port Fordwarding

Tags: ssh

I'm ussing this command to connect to my server and create a tunnel for MYSQL. Today I learn about ~/ssh/config and I want to know if it is possible to setup the port fordwarding in that file to able me to connect with an short name.

```
ssh admin@mydomain.com -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N -f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would use the `Host` option to specify a short name, and `User`, `Hostname`, `LocalForward` for the rest.

Example: http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/local/cs-arch-2002/http-tunnel-misc.html

TFM: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config

Comment: Thank you, thats awasome!! I dont know the linux ssh client have that!! is just amazing! now i love key auth, tunneling, and ssh config file!!